# Stuck on Child Component Communicating to Parent Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am super stuck on something. While I understand how a parent can pass props down to a child, I can't figure out how to use a child to communicate back up to a parent, grandparent, etc.

Basically, I have a child that is a nested component, and I want to make it so that, upon a click of this child component, another child is rendered at the same level as parent.

Here is my code...

```
var Grandparent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {closed: true};
  },
  checkMenuState: function() {
    if (this.state.closed == true) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        return <Child/>;
    }
  },
  handleState: function() {
    this.setState({closed: false});
    {this.checkMenuState}
  },
    render: function() {
    return <div><Parent/>{this.checkMenuState()}<OtherChild onClick={this.handleState}/></div>
  }
})

var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var parentSquare={backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 400, width: 400};
    return <div style={parentSquare}></div>;
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    var childSquare={backgroundColor: 'orange', height: 100, width: 100, top: 0, position: 'absolute'};
        return <div style={childSquare} closed={this.props.closed}></div>
  }
});

var OtherChild = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    var childSquare={backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: 100, width: 100, top: 100, position: 'absolute'};
        return <div style={childSquare}></div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Grandparent/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

So upon initial rendering, the page should look like this:[image: Iinitial rendering]

And then, once the yellow div is clicked, it should look like this:

[image: Rendering after yellow div onClick]

As of right now, nothing is happening when I click. Here is a link to my JSFiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/54400/#&togetherjs=5nEfQ04ktt/%22JSFiddle%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow your children to modify its parent's state you should pass a closure (a method with access to another scope) from the parent to the children. Notice that your so called "parent" is not a real parent ( :'( ) but a sibling of your child components. Only the Grandparent has inner components.

```js
var Grandparent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { showChild: false }
  },


  displayChild: function() {
    this.setState({ showChild: true })
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <Parent />
      { this.state.showChild ? <Child /> : undefined }
      <OtherChild onClick={ this.displayChild } />
    </div>
  }
})

var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var parentSquare = {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      height: 400,
      width: 400
    }

    return <div style={ parentSquare }></div>
  }
})

var Child = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var childSquare = {
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      top: 0,
      position: 'absolute'
    }

    return <div style={ childSquare }></div>
  }
})

var OtherChild = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var childSquare = {
      backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
      top: 100,
      position: 'absolute'
    }

    return <div style={ childSquare } onClick={ this.props.onClick }></div>
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <Grandparent/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
)
```

[Give it a try!](https://jsfiddle.net/jecjeg01/)

Comment: This only changes the state of the child component, but does not render a new child of the parent.

Comment: This enables the child to call a parent method that changes the parent's state. I'm not writing your specific logic so it remains abstracted to anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: Appreciate it, but I really need help with my specific example. It's not quite making sense to me.

Comment: @JessieRichardson answered

Comment: Thank you martriay!